# Do the bodies Orochimaru inhabits change to look like him?

Tags: naruto

Orochimaru takes on host bodies to maintain eternal youth. At least one of the bodies that he has taken on looks similar to him. The eyes, in particular, are very similar to his, as well as the skin tone.

Do the host bodies change to be more similar to his body?

Original body:

[image: Original body]

Host body

[image: Girl Orochimaru]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After researching in some wikis in spanish

[Orochimaru, Spanish Naruto Wikia](http://es.naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Orochimaru)

It is said that Orochimaru changes the host body to look similar to his original body. However he can't change the height of the new host.